# Checkers game - how to remove img or checker piece after a jump over

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

Just did a simple game of checkers, got the logic done of jumping or moving the checker pieces.

Now having problems on the actual logic of when a checker piece moves over or jumps over the other checker piece. How do i automatically remove or delete the checker piece that was jumped over?

Thanks so much :)

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>

        body { background-color: #D1CDDF; }

        p { font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
            font-size:  30; }

        img { width: 35px;
              height: 35px; }

        label { font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
                font-size: 15; }

        .focused{ border: 2px solid yellow; }

    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var moves = [];

        function saveScore() {
            // syntax: $.post(URL,data,callback);
            $.post("scores.php",
            {
                TheFile: $("#filename").val(),
                TheMessage: $("#winner").val() + "\r\n"
            }
            ,function(dataFromtheServer) {
                $("#result").html(dataFromtheServer);
            });
        }


        function openBoard()
        {   
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                var p1Name = document.getElementById("p1name").value;
                var p2Name = document.getElementById("p2name").value;

                var heading = "<center><p><font color=\"red\"><b>" + p1Name + "</b></font> vs <font color=\"blue\"><b>" + p2Name + "</b></font></p></center>";

                var table = $('<table width=500px cellspacing=0px cellpadding=0px border=1px ></table>');
                var rc;

                var picName;
                var picName2;

                for( y = 1; y <= 8; y++ )
                {
                    var row = $('<tr></tr>');

                    for ( var x = 1; x <= 8; x++)
                    {
                        rc = y + x;

                        // creating the images
                        picName = "p" + 1 + ".png" ;
                        var pic1 = $('<img>').attr('src',picName);

                        picName2 = "p" + 2 + ".png";
                        var pic2 = $('<img>').attr('src',picName2);

                        if(rc % 2 === 0)
                        {
                            if(y === 1 || y === 2 || y === 3)
                            {
                                var col1 = $('<td align=center height=50px width=50px bgcolor=#4E9660 ></td>').attr('id',y + '-' + x);

                                col1.html(pic1);

                                row.append(col1);  
                            }
                            else if(y === 6 || y === 7 || y === 8)
                            {
                                var col2 = $('<td align=center height=50px width=50px bgcolor=#4E9660 ></td>').attr('id',y + '-' + x);

                                col2.html(pic2);

                                row.append(col2);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var col3 = $('<td align=center height=50px width=50px bgcolor=#4E9660 ></td>').attr('id',y + '-' + x);

                                row.append(col3);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var col4 = $('<td align=center height=50px width=50px bgcolor=#C4C160 ></td>');

                            row.append(col4);
                        }
                    }

                table.append(row);

                }

                document.getElementById("bBoard").style.visibility = "hidden";
                $('#board').append(heading);
                $('#board').append(table);

                // setting the listener
                $('td').click(function()
                {
                    iAmtheClickListener(this.id);
                });

            });
        }


        function iAmtheClickListener(theID)
        {
            var r = $.inArray(theID,moves); // determine if the id is in the array
            var content = $("#"+theID).html();

            if( ((r < 0) && (content !== ""))  || ((r<0) && (moves.length == 1)) )
            {
                moves.push(theID);
                //change background color
                changeBackground("#"+theID,"yellow");
            }
            else
            {
                moves.splice(r,1); // to remove
                changeBackground("#"+theID,"#4E9660") ;
            }

            if (moves.length == 2)
            {
                var destId = moves[1] ;
                var srcId = moves[0] ;
                var srcImg = $("#" + srcId).html();

                $("#" + destId).html(srcImg);
                $("#" + srcId).html("");

                moves = [] ; // remove all
                changeBackground("#"+destId,"#4E9660") ;
                changeBackground("#"+srcId,"#4E9660") ;
            }

            $('#result').html(theID);
        }

        function changeBackground(theIdUwant, theColor)
        {
            $(theIdUwant).css("background-color",theColor);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <center>
    <p>~Checkers~</p>
    <table border=1 cellpadding=25px>
        <tr><td><label>Player 1: <input type=text id=p1name /></label><br/><br/>
                <label>Player 2: <input type=text id=p2name /></label><br/><br/>
                <button id="bBoard" onclick="openBoard();">Start Game</button><br/><br/></td>
        <td><div class="b" id="board"></div></td>
        <td>
            <input type=hidden id=filename value="players.txt" />
            <label>Register Winner: <input type=text id=winner /></label><br/><br/>
            <button id="bReg" onclick="saveScore();">Submit</button><br/><br/>
            <div id="result"></div>    
        </td>
        </td></tr>
    </table>
    </center>

</body>
```

Comment: i  think you should check start and finish of moving checker. your coordinates will be: x - index of table cell, y - index of table row
if you jump over some checker, call $(checkerYouJumpOver).remove(); and i found that in your game player can move checker ON other checker. you should check availability of cell before moving checker

Comment: Why is this tagged java? This looks like a javascript problem. http://javascriptisnotjava.io/

Comment: Apart from what @bearwithbeard have suggested, I think it would be a good idea for you to have 2d array checking the board (with value of 0 meaning nothing, 1 meaning player 1, 2 meaning player 2). This way, you can keep track of the game based on the numerical array rather html elements (ie separating UI and logic underneath).

Comment: @Tim1234, totally agree

Comment: @javaMan1995 and with this 2d array you can check when game is over and the fact that you can move only by one cell. now you can take some checker at one end of the board and put it where you want

Answer (score 0):

Suppose jumped piece is at `board[row][col]`, you can assign a value of zero or empty at that particular cell after being jumped:

```
board[row][col] = EMPTY
```